# PHP: Get all images from a folder but not subfolder

Tags: php

I have a code here that gets all images in a folder including subfolders. What can i do to fetch images only from the folder but not the subfolder?

```
$dirname = "media/images/iconized/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

Comment: that doesn't fetch images from subfolders

Comment: If theres a subfolder, it fetches the subfolder name. (Ex: Subfolder name:abc, it also fetches <img src="media/images/iconized/abc/" > along with other images)

Comment: ok then, answer in the way, but it shouldn't as the folder name would have to be `something.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dirname = "media/images/iconized/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");
foreach($images as $image) {
    if(!is_dir($image))
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used directory iterator with filter iterator to get file list of specific extension. Have a look on below solution. You can use recursivedirectory iterator to get files recursively.

```
class FileExtFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    private $fileext;

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, $fileext)
    {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->fileext = $fileext;
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        $file = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return preg_match("/\.({$this->fileext})$/", $file);
    }
}
function getFilteredFileList($dir, $ext)
{
    $retval = array();

    // add trailing slash if missing
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // open directory for reading
    $d = new DirectoryIterator($dir) or die("getFilteredFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    $iterator = new FileExtFilter($d, $ext);
    foreach($iterator as $fileinfo) {

        if($fileinfo->isDot()) continue;
        $retval[] = array(
            'name' => "{$dir}{$fileinfo}",
            'type' => ($fileinfo->getType() == "dir") ? "dir" : mime_content_type($fileinfo->getRealPath()),
            'size' => $fileinfo->getSize(),
            'lastmod' => $fileinfo->getMTime()
        );
    }

    return $retval;
}

$list = getFilteredFileList('directorypath', 'png|jpeg|pdf');

print_r($list);
```